# What is the difference between loop and iteration?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, programming-languages

What kinds of data structure are used to implement loop and iteration?

Comment: -1, the question is ill-formed. The question is like asking what kind of words are used with language.

Comment: I Just rush into this issue recently. I'd like to write down how I understand them: **Iteration** is a process that one constantly does repeatedly to achieve a specific purpose obvious to the system and outside world, whereas **loop** normally means a repeated code segment within an iteration process, that's why one iteration may consist of one or many loops, as Gaurav told in his anwer. We can say **iteration** is a **cycle** but we don't say **cycle** in "process" world. Actually **cycle** is mostly existed in H/W, communication, or queuing system worlds.

Answer (score 6):

Loop refers to the code...
iteration refers to the process in which the content of loop is executed once..
so 1 iteration refers to 1 time execution of loop.. 
so basically one loop can undergo many iterations..

Comment: Personally, I don't like, and I avoid, the use of word 'iteration' to mean _"b. One cycle of a set of instructions to be repeated"_ despite the fact this definition is one of the two definitions given by (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iteration). Personnaly, I consider to be valid only the first definition: _"a. The process of repeating a set of instructions a specified number of times or until a specific result is achieved."_ I don't understand that people accept the ambiguities and confusion arised by the use of a word to mean together something and a part of this something!!

Comment: For _"One cycle of a set of instructions to be repeated"_ , I use the words 'cycle' (what a trick !) or 'turn'. I do the same in french and it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

loop is used for fixed no. of element or certain condition occurs while iterator is used for itearing element dynamically that have different no. of elements at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Only such of kind 1.

Some have tried using data structures of kind 42 for this purpose, but failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is simply the number of time/times a loop can be executed, while loop is the code which generate or causes expressions to be iterated iteration when the loop is executing.

An example of lines of code in c++:

```
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
   {
   cout<<"this is printed 10 times";
   }
```

The above code is a for_loop in which the execution of the statement "this is printed 10 times" will be iterated/repeated 10 times.

Comment: The question was asked a long time ago and was asking about data structures, not the difference between loop and iteration.